# Power Query error while using a parameter

Tags: parameters, powerquery

I am trying to create a parameter from a named range so it can be used in Power Query.
This parameter is to be used in a path to open a file (txt, csv or xlsx).

**Named range**: p_YearMonth

```
=TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY();-1);"yyyymm")
```

**Parameter in PWQ**: Advanced Editor

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="p_YearMonth"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    Column1 = #"Changed Type"{0}[Column1]
in
    Column1
```

**Query to open the file - Without Parameter**: Works just fine

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("D:\myfiles\202205\test.txt"),[Delimiter=";", Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
in
    Source
```

**Query to open the file - With Parameter**: Does not Work

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("D:\myfiles\" & p_YearMonth & "\test.txt"),[Delimiter=";", Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
in
    Source
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**
Formula.Firewall: Query 'Query1' (step 'Source') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.

What am I doing wrong?

Regards, Elio Fernandes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it together on a single query

```
let
yearmonth= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="p_YearMonth"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("D:\myfiles\"&yearmonth&"\test.txt"),[Delimiter=";", Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
in Source
```

Comment: It works great! Can you explain why we must put it together?

Comment: I'd like to. It it's just crazy powerquerys annoying firewall nonsense